# Pasting double quotes " " in R

Tags: r, paste

I'm trying to paste a series of string of characters like this:

```
paste0("//*[@id=",'"set_',1,'_div"]/a')
[1] "//*[@id=\"set_1_div\"]/a"
```

How can I get rid of the "\"? This is my expected outcome

```
[1] "//*[@id="set_1_div"]/a"
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try running `x <- paste0("//*[@id=",'"set_',1,'_div"]/a'); x == '//*[@id="set_1_div"]/a'` and then decide whether you think the "extra" slashes are "actually there".

Comment: Also, to see that this is just a matter of R's default print method displaying `"` with a prepended escape character, try this: `print(paste0("//*[@id=",'"set_',1,'_div"]/a'), quote=FALSE)`

Comment: OMG, I spend so much time in this, it was really simple...

Answer (score 3):

The backslash designates that the next character needs to be 'escaped', i.e., it does not need to be interpreted as being part of an expression, but rather as a character. When using the print statement, character strings are quoted and therefore the escape sign (backslash) is included. However, using the cat statement you can easily see that the backslashes are not actualy part of the character string:

```
> x <- paste0("//*[@id=",'"set_',1,'_div"]/a')
> x
[1] "//*[@id=\"set_1_div\"]/a"
> cat(x)
//*[@id="set_1_div"]/a
```